# How to deal with transitive functional dependency in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm relatively new to MySQL. Thank you in advance if any of you could point a direction on my problem. I am stuck on my project on the problem below. I have a data table below to show insurance premiums under different insurance variants.

| ins_id (PK) | insurance_type | local_household (Variant A) | ss_medical_level (Variant B) | company_type (Variant C) | base | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ss_pension | yes |  |  | x | x |
| 2 | ss_pension | no |  |  | x | x |
| 3 | ss_medical | yes |  |  | x | x |
| 4 | ss_medical | no | first | corporation | x | x |
| 5 | ss_medical | no | first | non_corporation | x | x |
| 6 | ss_medical | no | second |  | x | x |
| 7 | ss_medical | no | third |  | x | x |

Variant C -> Variant B -> Variant A. They are transitive functional dependent by the sequence C > B > A

(-> means depends on)

In short, I am seeking a way to maintain these variants.
What I am trying to achieve is to design a schema to maintain the variants, and make it possible for easy future sustainable management on the variants. There will be more variants added for other types insurance. I had a draft design on the schema relations, but I am stuck on the variants part. I still did not get my head around on the transitive functional dependency design.

[my current schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3FWl.png)

Comment: Could you have something like c depends on b which depends on a, but also e depends on d which depends on a, like a tree. That would form a dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks man. I will look into "dependency tree" to see if I can find solution myself.

Comment: What I mean is that you need to understand what kind of structure you have, then you can lookup how to represent such structure in a RDBMS. You might want to take a quick look at graph theory concepts.

Comment: Yes, I know what kind of structure I need. c depends on b which depends on an in the sample table. The dependency path might be also like c depends on a (directly). Variants d, e, f etc could be added in the future. Thanks. I will look at graph theory concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the direction to solve my problem. I got inspired by this thread to use a path enumeration method.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuH5OoPC3hA